# Proof that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are also independent

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove this for the discrete case. What I've done so far is:

$$P_{x,y}(f(X),\ g(Y)) = P_{x,y}(f(X) = k,\ g(Y) = m) = P_{x,y}(X = f^{-1}(k),\ Y = g^{-1}(m))$$

Since X and Y are independent, this tells us that the above is equal to:
$$P_x(f^{-1}(k))\ P_y(g^{-1}(k))$$

But, I'm stuck on where to go from here. I'm not really sure if what I did above is enough proof (pretty certain it's not).

Apologies in advance if anything I've written is incorrect/looks dumb. I'm not really well versed with proofs.

Comment: Food for thought: why would $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of independence states that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if for sets of the form $E_1 = (-\infty, a)$, $E_2 = (-\infty, b)$, $P(X \in E_1) \cdot P(Y \in E_2) = P(X \in E_1 \land Y \in E_2)$.

Recall we can show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if for all measurable sets $E_1, E_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $P(X \in E_1) \cdot P(Y \in E_2) = P(X \in E_1 \land Y \in E_2)$. This characterisation of independence is harder to prove that the definition of independence but easier to apply, so we will use it here.

Suppose that $f, g$ are measurable functions.

Note that $f(X) \in E_1$ iff $X \in f^{-1}(E_1)$, and $g(Y) \in E_2$ iff $Y \in g^{-1}(E_2)$. Note that both $f^{-1}(E_1)$ and $g^{-1}(E_2)$ are measurable.

Then we see that

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(f(X) \in E_1) \cdot P(g(Y) \in E_2) 
&= P(X \in f^{-1}(E_1)) \cdot P(y \in g^{-1}(E_2)) \\
&= P(X \in f^{-1}(E_1) \land Y \in g^{-1}(E_2)) \\
&= P(f(X) \in E_1 \land g(Y) \in E_2)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

as required.